# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una promesa únicamente si retorna error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios, try-catch

Estoy trabajando con react y redux : el error ocurre cuando desde otro componente quiero obtener el valor que retorna la funcion actionToken() => pero SOLO lo quiero obtener cuando devuelva un error:
Funcion:

```
export  function actionToken( email, password) {
  return async (dispatch)=>{
    try{
      let datos = await axios.post("***", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
      let data = datos.data.token;
      dispatch(ActionLogged(data));
      return data;
    } catch (err){
      dispatch(ActionLoggedFalse);
      let objerror = {
        type: 'error',
        errorinfo: err
      }
      return objerror;
    }
  };
}
```

Tratando de obtener el valor desde otro componente PERO SOLO CUANDO DEVUELVE UN ERROR:
-Hasta el momento solo puedo obtener el error de la siguiente manera:

```
 return actionToken(values.username, values.password)
           .then(resp=> {
            if(resp.type == 'error'){
              console.log(resp.errormessage);
            }
          });
        }
```

y mi intención es obtenerlo con el .catch pero no me retorna nada , ejemplo:

```
return actionToken(values.username, values.password)
.catch((resp)=> {
            console.log(resp.type)//
          }
```

Comment: Las evaluaciones de `resp.type`  entiendo que son  en caso que la transacción sea exitosa, es decir que esta bien como lo has hecho y no como lo estás intentando.

Comment: @Emeeus Gracias por responder,  el objerror se enviará en caso de que halla ocurrido un error con la  petición de tipo POST,  es por eso que quiero obtener el valor solo cuando ocurra un error , pero utilizando catch no puedo hacerlo

Comment: Claro pero en ese caso tienes que hacer un `throw objerror` en lugar de `return objerror`, de manera de "crear" el error. Lo que en mi opinión es polémco en ese caso es que lances un error dentro de justamente un `catch` para que lo capture otro `catch`.